# Docker dnu restore fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docker

I am testing ASP.NET 5 docker image on linux Ubuntu and command dnu restore fails:

> Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
>
> Error: NameResolutionFailure

If I run dnu restore from command line all is ok.

Is Docker image provided from Microsoft (Microsoft / ASP.NET) broken?

This is the Dockerfile content:

> ```
> FROM microsoft/aspnet 
> ENV MONO_THREADS_PER_CPU 2000
> COPY project.json /app/
> WORKDIR /app
> RUN ["dnu", "restore"]
> COPY . /app
> EXPOSE 5000
> ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "-p", "project.json", "kestrel"]
> ```

Comment: I have the same issue, but when I try the same setup from my home PC it restores the packages correctly. That leads me to believe that it's related to the Network settings at my workplace.